# Circular walk-in shower remodel- waterproofing windows and walls with purple board?

Tags: shower, backer-board

Thanks in advance for any insight you may be able to throw my way..
my in-laws are in the process of fixing a shower due to water damage. It is a circular walk-in shower with a vaulted cedar ceiling. The shower walls are about 140 sq feet, the shower floor is about 134 sq ft + 1 step. It contains four windows. The contractor on the job informed them that he would be installing either green or purple board around the shower and then they would Red guard the entire area. He also said they would be adding wire mesh which would allow the tile to adhere to the wall. Yesterday his guys came in and installed 1/2in Purple Board from ceiling to about a foot from the floor. No backer board was placed in the windows. From what I have gathered using a cement board such as perma-based flex on the walls will bend to the radius of the shower much better than purple board. Then a membrane like redguard can be placed over the cement board and then tile. The same process would be done for the windows. The tile can be placed directly on the Red guard right? Placing wire mesh over the Red guard would puncture the membrane? The reason they stopped the purple board foot or so from the shower floor was so that the shower floor can be hot mopped, I think? I attached some pictures.. I'm not sure how important it is that the purple board not have gaps in between it or broken corners? They also didn't place a piece of wood along with backer board all the way to the bottom of the cedar ceiling there's a huge gap.The windows are the same with a large gap between the window framing and the window itself. After looking at what they did it just looks incomplete and very sloppy. Not to mention that the contractors bid to the insurance company is close to $20,000. I'm just trying to make sure that the process is done correctly. If anybody has any advice as to backer-board and how to waterproof the windows that would be great. I believe the contractor supposed to be here next week and I just want to be armed with some information before that. Thank you again.[image: pics]

Comment: Without knowing his full plan, I cannot give an answer, only head you in the right direction. Yes Redgard will take tile directly. No need for any other surface to go over it for tile. You are right, the fasteners to hold the mesh will put holes in the Redgard, rendering it almost worthless. Redgard is also used for the most part as a complete waterproofing system, floor an all. I have no idea how they plan to tie the 2 together, where the hot mop and purple board meet. Typically the hot mop is first and wall board (cement board) is placed over the hot mopped at the walls close to the floor.

Comment: In my experience there are "tile setters" and then there are "shower installers." The former might set tile fine, but don't understand water management, whereas the latter know how to set tile **and** properly manage water. Getting the details right to correctly manage water is difficult. It appears that your contractor doesn't have a clue. Moreover, you have a very custom shower with curved walls. This is a difficult job and requires an expert. Having gone through a bad experience myself, I'd strongly advise cutting ties with this contractor now. I doubt he will be able make it right.